# Issues with FlexBox Justify Property

Tags: css, flexbox

I have problems with implementing justify content using flexbox. The `.help` and `.main-nav` classes should be up against the right of their containers when using `justify-content:space-between/around`.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/bmoneruiux/full/pJJvpa)

I'm getting this odd behavior after wrapping the children in a container DIV for centering purposes, and now `justify-content` doesn't work.

Comment: Does FlexBox have to have defined width's? Or can it work with unknown widths? I'm truly at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so all of my issues sim from the skeleton framework. Nothing was wrong with my coding. Took me doing some high level code stripping to figure that out. I'll never use skeleton again.